# Does the speed of a wave travelling through a chain vary based on the size of the links?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

If you have a single, linear, physical, steel chain, and you initiate a wave motion that travels through this chain, how would the speed or momentum of the wave vary based on the thickness and/or length of each link in the chain?

Assume that the force applied to the wave, the total length of the chain, the total weight of the chain, and all other characteristics remain the same -- the only variables are the thicknesses and lengths of the individual links in the chain.

Similarly, how would the speed or momentum of that same wave be different if there were no links at all in the chain, but rather a continuous steel cable of the same weight and length, but just in cable form vs. in chain link form.

Comment: -1. No research effort. Try googling waves on strings.

Comment: Why are people on this forum so rude? I did search for it, but strings are not chains. Very different question.

Comment: No rudeness was intended. Do you take all criticism as rudeness? It would be reasonable to model waves on a chain of many links in the same way as a wave on a string, so that's a good place to start. Or do you have any better ideas?

Comment: @sammygerbil well, to knock the question assuming I did no research, and telling me to "google strings", yeah, that's kinda rude. But glad it is not intentional. Asking about two different chains, one with small links, another with large links. Strings don't seem to provide me with guidance to answer that, but I'm all ears, thanks.

Comment: I don't see any sign of research, or analytical effort, in your question. You appear to be asking "Here is a problem, solve it for me."

Comment: @sammygerbil it's is a yes or no question and doesn't yet exist on this forum and could not find it on Google.  If you think it is not a valid or interesting question, you can ignore it and move on.

Comment: The model as a continuum would be better as you take smaller links.